# JavaScript confirm delete not working

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I am using cakephp version 2.x.

I am getting one trouble while deleting any record. I want to show confirmation message before delete my record. The JavaScript onclick function not working. Please check below code.

Code:

```
<?php
  echo $this->Html->image('delete.png', array(
  'title' => 'Delete',
  'alt' =>'Delete' ,
  'url' => array(
    'controller' => 'products',
    'action' => 'deletequery/'.$query['Query']['id']),array('confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete?')
    )
  );
?>
```

OutPut:

```
<a href="/products/deletequery/15">
   <img delete?="Are you sure you want to delete?" to="" want="" sure="" you="" are="" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/img/delete.png">
</a>
```

Comment: You should read this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794213/image-link-with-confirmmessage-alert-in-cakephp-htmlhelper-possible

Comment: Looks like you need to learn how to count braces (or parenthesis, in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this because your code is incorrect.

```
<?php 
 echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('delete.png'),
    array(
        'controller'=>'products',
        'action'=>'deletequery',$query['Query']['id']
    ),
    array('confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete?','escape'=>false)
 );
?>
```

**Output**

```
<a 
  onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) 
  { return true; } return false;" 
  href="/ABC/products/deletequery">
  <img alt="" src="/ABC/img/delete.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You should try this in your view file there are basically two methods to delete a file.
>   first is you can simply make cakephp `$this->Html->link` or seceond method you can make a `$this->Form->postLink` both are different. the difference between both are `postLink` creates a "Form tag" but `link` tag not create "Form" tag
>
> **1. $this->Html->link**

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('delete.png').'', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'deletequery',$query['Query']['id']),array('confirm'=>'Are you sure to delete ?','escape'=>false));
?>
```

**2. $this->Form->postLink**

```
<?php 
 echo $this->Form->postLink($this->Html->image('delete.png').'', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'deletequery',$query['Query']['id']),array('confirm'=>'Are you sure to delete ?','escape'=>false));
 ?>
```

you can visit cakephp blog tutorial
[cakephp blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html)